# How to escape soapui variable pattern in the json request

Tags: json, soapui

I have a JSON request for my API it takes input string as a pattern `${some.input}` which is equivalent to SoapUI properties expansion

`request.json` looks like:

```
{
    "config": {
        "logmsg": "${some.input}",
        "logfile": "kilores.log",
        "loglevel": "${#TestCase#api_name}"
    }
}
```

when I send an sopaui request the raw looks like

```
{
    "config": {
        "logmsg": "",
        "logfile": "kilores.log",
        "loglevel": "info"
    }
}
```

The issue here is that SoapUI assumes `${some.input}` belongs to SoapUI properties expansion and needs to be evaluated. Actually `${some.input}` is part of the API JSON request and **should not** get evaluated by SoapUI before sending it. How can I achieve this? I have other SoapUI variables (like `${#TestCase#api_name}`) in the same request that must be evaluated but not that particular one that belongs to the actual request.

Comment: Does `"\${some.input}"` work?

Comment: That is illegal escape character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is little trivial one. As you pointed correctly, it was being treated by soapui as `property expansion` and that is the reason it is being sent as `"logmsg" : ""`

All you need to do is add an additional `$`. Hence your request should be as shown below:

```json
{
    "config": {
        "logmsg": "$${some.input}",
        "logfile": "kilores.log",
        "loglevel": "${#TestCase#api_name}"
    }
}
```